# Optimal way to multiply 3D matrices in GNU/Octave

Tags: png, octave, matrix-multiplication

We have a 50x50x3 matrix `i` loaded with `imread` from a PNG file, made of 0s and 1s (fore/background). The image is to be inked with a given color, a vector `c` of 1x3 numbers in [0,1] (RGB), resulting in `c(k)` replacing the 1s in `i(:,:,k)` (`k` in [1...3]), and leaving the 0s unchanged.
What would be the expression with a minimal computing time to perform this operation (sort of matrix multiplication) on these to variables?

Comment: you really should start adding a [MCVE] Without this you ask others to create a sample input before writing the code anf guess the expected output. Make it as easy as possible to help you and you'll get fast and good answers

Comment: @Andy you are absolutely right, thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by reshaping `c` to be a 1x1x3 array:

```
c = reshape(c,1,1,3);
```

Next, do a point-wise multiplication. Octave (as does the newest MATLAB) does implicit singleton expansion (aka broadcasting):

```
 i = i .* c;
```

Comment: Works nicely. Really, I can't think of a simpler and faster way.